# Rails 5.1 Multiple belongs_to associations with optional: true, rollback - 'required association'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.1, rails-5.1.6

I want to use `belongs_to parent_model, optional: true` assocation for 1 child - and 2 parents. Found this answer: [Model belongs_to eiher/or more than one models](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48486797/model-belongs-to-eiher-or-more-than-one-models). Tried that. But with 2 associated parent models one of them causes rollback when saving the child model.

Is there any limitation on `belongs_to` with multiple parent models and `optional: true`? Or am I missing some other presence validation?
Important to say: *I would rather avoid using polymorphic associations in this case.*

PrivateAttachment has a file attached using Paperclip.
private_attachment.rb

```
Class PrivateAttachment < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :first_class, optional: true
  belongs_to :second_class, optional: true

  has_attached_file :certificate

  validates_attachment_presence :certificate
  validates_attachment_size :certificate, :less_than => 10.megabytes
  validates_attachment_content_type :certificate,
    :content_type => [
      "image/jpg", 
      "image/jpeg", 
      "image/png", 
      "application/pdf",
      "file/txt",
      "text/plain",
      "application/doc",
      "application/msword", 
      "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
      "application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text",
      ]

end
```

first_class.rb

```
Class FirstClass < ApplicationRecord

  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 2000, allow_blank: true

  has_many :private_attachments, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :approvals
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :approvals

end
```

second_class.rb

```
Class SecondClass < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :private_attachments, dependent: :destroy

end
```

When creating PrivateAttachment:

```
second_class.private_attachments.new(certificate: file)
```

there's a Rollback on save with a message, despite optional attribute is set to true.

Full error

> ActiveModel::Errors:0x00007f8bbe03a380 @base=#PrivateAttachment id:
>   nil, first_class_id: nil, company_id: nil, user_id: nil, doc_type:
>   nil, url: nil, active: nil, blind: nil, permit_period: nil, views:
>   nil, downloads: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil,
>   certificate_file_name: "test.pdf", certificate_content_type:
>   "application/pdf", certificate_file_size: 443632,
>   certificate_updated_at: "2018-07-24 20:18:20", second_class_id: 23>,
>   @messages={:first_class=>["First class required."]},
>   **@details={:first_class=>[{:error=>:blank}]}>

When creating Attachment with a first_class, everything works just fine, no error.

UPDATE 1---------------------------------------------------------------------

I just realized, that `first_class` has a child model `Approval` which has own validation. But at this point I don't understand why should be this deep assocation being taken into consideration when using `optional: true`  ?

```
approval.rb

class Approval < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :job_application

  validates_acceptance_of :operator_approval, :allow_nil => false,

end
```

Rails 5.1.6. 
PG DB

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me but who knows what magic might be happening there. Can you try moving `belongs_to :second_class, optional: true` above `belongs_to :first_class, optional: true` in model definition and see if `second_class.private_attachments.create(certificate: file)` works?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Did try that as well before with new-> save. The same error (updated full error message). And now tried with .create -> No new record in PrivateAttachment table.

Comment: Made an update in the question itself. Not sure if deeper associations might be a problem in case of the first_class.